# I can't find where the example tools installed by the ui_tool_simple.py python template showed up. Where are they?

Tags: python

I would like to write my own tools in python, and so I'm starting with the template.  When I run the ui_tool_simple.py python template python script, I can't tell what it did.  I know it did something, because when I run it twice, I get a "Tool XXXX already exists!"  I just am not sure where to look.

I'd like to be able to find my tool when I write it.  But if I can't find this, then I sure as hell won't be able to find mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those seems to be the new tools...

[image: tools]

Comment: You are right.  Thanks!